# Tikz pictures disappears when adding legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(axis cs:40,20)},anchor=south west, draw=none},
    xmin=0,xmax=4,
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style=->,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=0:3,samples=100]{(1/9) *x^2}; 
    %\legend{$f(x)=frac{1}{9}x^2$} 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

If i uncomment the legend line, my pictures doesn't appear in my pdf. Anyone know why ?

> \legend{$f(x)=frac{1}{9}x^2$}

Comment: Note that you also miss a ; after the `\legend`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a result of the `legend style`. You've placed the legend way outside the axis limits. The reason you don't see anything at all can be seen by adding `\fill[red!20] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);` just before `\end{tikzpicture}`. Essentially, the axis is at the bottom left of the tikzpicture, and the legend in the top right. But because the `tikzpicture` is so large, you're only seeing the upper left corner, where there is nothing.

Remove `at={(axis cs:40,20)},anchor=south west,` from the `label style`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
   legend style={%at={(axis cs:40,20)},anchor=south west,
    draw=none},
    xmin=0,xmax=4,
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style=->,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=0:3,samples=100]{(1/9) *x^2}; 
    \legend{$f(x)=\frac{1}{9}x^2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]